# What exactly is a random variable?

Tags: random-variables, terminology, definition

I don't really understand the definition of a random variable. I also find the Wikipedia entry on random variables kind of confusing.

Can someone give me a clear explanation of the random variable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given a  [universal sample space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_space) $\Omega$ such that

> $$\Omega =\{\text {all possible outcomes (non-predetermined ) of an experiment }\}$$

Let note $n=\text{card}(\Omega) $, $\Omega= \{ \omega_i,\ 1\le i \le n\}$

Now let's define a function $X$ such that  $$\begin{array}{ll}X:& \Omega& \rightarrow &\mathbb R \\& \omega_i&\mapsto &X(\omega_i)\end{array}$$
$X(\omega_i)$ is the value of the random variable $X$ at the event $\omega_i \in \Omega$.

Note that this function can be anything as it depends on the experiment, take for examples

- The outcome of throwing a die. $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $X(\omega_i)=\omega_i \in \Omega$
- Throwing two dice at a time, the sum of the results from both dice. $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \times \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $X(\Omega)=\{2,3,4,\cdots,12\}$
  with $X(\omega)=\alpha+\beta$ if $\omega=(\alpha,\beta)$
- Throwing a coin where $\text{Head}=1 \text{ point}$ and $\text{Tail}=-1 \text{ point}$
  $\Omega=\{\text{Head}, \text{ Tail}\}$ and $X(\Omega)=\{-1,1\}$ with $X(\text{Head})=+1$ and $X(\text{Tail})=-1$

These are all discrete random variables (probability mass function), one can also have continuous random variables where $\omega_i$ take values in $\mathbb R$,

> Let $X$ be a random variable whose distribution function $F_X$ has a derivative. The function $f_X$ satisfying $$F_X(x)= \int^x_{-\infty} f_X(t)dt$$ is called the **probability density function** and X is called a **continuous random variable.**

Comment: Please be more careful: both [*$X(\omega_i)$ is the random variable associated with the event $\omega_i \in \Omega$*] and [*and $X(\omega_i)=\{-1,1\}$*] are wrong.

Comment: @did I had a feeling I mixed the terminologies up. I would appreciate it if you correct them. Thank you.

Comment: @did Thank you, I'll pay more attention in the future.

Comment: You seem to imply that $\Omega$ is finite. Am I misreading? Is this intentional?

Comment: @MJD $\Omega$ is not necessarily finite.

Answer (score 15):

A random variable is nothing more or less than a *function* on a probability space with values in ${\mathbf R}$. First we need to be clear about what a probability space is, and then a random variable is a function from such a space to the real numbers. That is, what makes random variables special is the type of space on which they are defined.

A *probability space* is set $\Omega$ on which we can talk sensibly about the probability of selecting an element from a subset of $\Omega$.

Example 1. Let $\Omega$ be the outcomes of flipping a coin twice: $\Omega = \{(H,H),(H,T),(T,H),(T,T)\}$.  If the coin is fair and the flips are done independently, then we assign each element of $\Omega$ the probability 1/4, and from this we can produce further probabilities, such as the probability of having at least one head (that is, selecting from $\{(H,H),(H,T),(T,H)\}$) being 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/4 = 3/4.  If we had an unfair coin where $H$ comes up with probability 1/3 and $T$ comes up with probability 2/3, and the two flips are independent then $(H,H)$ has probability 1/9, $(H,T)$ and $(T,H)$ each have probability 2/9, and $(T,T)$ has probability 4/9. Now the probability of two (independent) flips of this coin having at least one $H$ is 1/9 + 2/9 + 2/9 = 5/9 < 3/4. If the two coin flips were not independent, then you could not determine the probability of a particular pair of coin flips from knowledge of the probability of $H$ or $T$ separately.

Example 2. Let $\Omega$ be the unit disc in the plane, centered at the origin.  One probability distribution on $\Omega$ is the uniform distribution: the probability a randomly selected point from $\Omega$ lies in a subset $S$ is the area of $S$ divides by $\pi$ (the area of $\Omega$).  Another probability distribution on $\Omega$ is the Dirac distribution at the origin: the probability that a randomly selected point from $\Omega$ lies in any subset $S$ of $\Omega$ is 1 if $(0,0) \in S$ and 0 otherwise.  There are lots of probability distributions on the unit disc, and the particular choice you make determines what it means to pick a point from the disc randomly (according to the chosen probability distribution on the unit disc).

In practice, a probability space is the set of possible outcomes of an experiment, but mathematically a probability space is just a set on which we can speak about selecting elements from that space lying in different subsets.

A *random variable* on a probability space $\Omega$ is a function $\Omega \rightarrow {\mathbf R}$, and for historical reasons such functions are denoted by letters like $X$ or $Y$ (rather than $f$ or $g$). Because $X$ has real values, we can define the probability that $X$ has values in the interval $[2,5]$, say, to be the probability of selecting an element of $\Omega$ from $\{\omega \in \Omega : 2 \leq X(\omega) \leq 5\}$.  The probability $X$ has a positive value is declared to be the probability of selecting an element of $\Omega$ from $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) > 0\}$. In other words, because $X$ is defined on a set $\Omega$ in which we can talk about the probability of picking elements from subsets of $\Omega$, we can transfer this probability mechanism over to intervals in ${\mathbf R}$ by looking at the subsets of $\Omega$ consisting of those elements where $X$ has values in a chosen real interval.

In many areas of math, you study spaces by studying real-valued functions on them, such as continuous functions on topological spaces or smooth functions on manifolds. One hopes that important properties of the space are reflected in the types of real-valued functions you can reasonably define on that space (continuous, smooth,...). In probability theory, one probes the "structure" of a  probability space $\Omega$ by working with the real-valued functions on $\Omega$  in order to transfer the probabilities of subsets of $\Omega$ to probabilities of subsets of ${\mathbf R}$, because on ${\mathbf R}$ you can do things that may not be directly possible in $\Omega$ itself (e.g., *add* the values of two random variables on $\Omega$; it may not make sense to add elements of $\Omega$ directly, such as the case of outcomes of coin flips as $H$ or $T$).

I have assumed that you don't know measure theory, so I glossed over measure-theoretic technicalities above in order to convey the basic idea of what a random variable is. In the language of measure theory, a probability space is a measure space equipped with a measure giving the whole space measure 1 and a random variable on $\Omega$ is defined to be a real-valued measurable function on $\Omega$.

Comment: You said random variable is just a function in first paragraph and in your last paragraph you said it is measurable function. so every function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$ is measurable .or i got it wrong . i.e not every function is random variable

Comment: @MeetPatel note how I started the last paragraph: "I have assumed that you don't know measure theory, so I glossed over measure-theoretic technicalities above in order to convey the basic idea". That is an essential aspect of my answer. Only in the last paragraph did I get more precise by allowing myself to use ideas from measure theory.  When explaining what a random variable is to someone who does not know measure theory, it is not a good idea to refer to the measurability condition.

Answer (score 4):

A random variable is a function whose value is known only after some underlying uncertainty about the world is resolved. So for example, suppose there is some source of uncertainty in the physical world say temperature at noon tomorrow. We may have a good idea what the temperature is likely to be because of past history and weather models so we may have a probability distribution of what the temperature is likely to be at noon but we don't know for a fact if it is going to be some exact number up to some decimal places.

Now suppose you enter into a bet with a friend that says that for every degree the temperature is above 40 degrees he pays you 1 dollar and if the temperature is below 40 degrees then nothing happens. Your payoff from this bet depends on what temperature is measured at noon tomorrow. It can vary depending on what the temperature winds up being. The payoff from the bet is a function of the way the underlying uncertainty is resolved. The cashflow from this bet is a random variable. A random variable is just a function whose value we don't know right now and whose value can be different depending on how some underlying uncertainty is resolved but once the uncertainty is resolved we know the value of the function.

Answer (score 3):

A *random variable* $X$ is a function  in the usual sense (e.g., with real values), defined on a probability space $\Omega$: For each "elementary event" $\omega\in\Omega$ a certain value $X(\omega)$ is defined. What's "random" about it are the points $\omega\in\Omega$  where $X$ is evaluated: The  payoff $X$ depends in an previously agreed way on the number of spots thrown. In most applications (e.g., when talking about weather) the space $\Omega$ is huge and devoid of a description by means of finitely many coordinates or of other simple structure. Therefore one avoids to take a precise look at the elementary events $\omega$. Nevertheless the whole theory is set up in such a way that it makes precise sense to talk about the "probability that $X$ has a value $\leq x$" or that two different random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on $\Omega$ are "independent".

Comment: I'm not sure how "the number of eyes thrown" got in there, but if you are referring to the throw of a die or dice, the usual word in English is "spots" or "pips", not "eyes".

Comment: @MJD: Thank you; I've edited that. In German it's "Augen".

Answer (score 2):

## Intuitive, less mathematical explanation

We can build a strong intuition about what a **random variable** is if we understand the term **variable** itself.

Below is a simple equation:
$$y = x + 2$$
Both $y$ and $x$ are some *variables*. I can now **arbitrarily** choose $x$ to be equal to $5$ and check that $y$ must therefore be equal to $7$. Moreover, I can personally choose any number for $x$ and later on calculate $y$. Both $x$ and $y$ are *variables* since their values can vary.  Pretty straightforward, right?

A *random variable* is like any other *variable*, but I can't simply choose its value. Random variable gets its value from some experiment that we conduct (I've heard people say that "nature" assigns value to the *random variable*). Let's see some examples!

### Example #1

Imagine we are playing a cardboard game. Every time we throw a die, we are running an experiment! Let $X$ be our *random variable* and let it stand for the resulting number of dots on our die after a throw. It is a **variable** since there are many possible outcomes. Specifically, we can get $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ or $6$. At the same time, $X$ is a **random variable** since I need to run an experiment to see what value will be finally assigned to it. This means I can't just arbitrarily choose its value.

$X$ = number of dots on the face of our die after a throw.

Interesting, additional fact: The set of possible outcomes of our throw: {$1,2,3,4,5,6$}, is called the *support* of $X$.

### Example #2

Every time you go shopping, you run an experiment. Let $Y$ be a *random variable* and let it signify how much money do you spend in the mall. You can spend different amounts of money there starting from $0$, so $Y$ is a **variable**. On top of that $Y$ is a **random variable** since you need to go shopping (run the experiment) to know what will be its value.

$Y$ = the amount of money spent in the mall.

### In short

You can think of a *random variable* as an ordinary *variable*, which value is chosen after running some experiment.

### Additional remarks about probability distributions

Some people confuse *random variables* with their *probability distributions*, so I will try to shortly explain what's the difference between these two terms. *Probability distribution* simply describes to us how likely are different outcomes or, in other words,  what are the probabilities of different outcomes. More specifically: how likely is a *random variable* to assume a certain value after running an experiment. *Probability distributions*, therefore, tell us what values we can expect from a *random variable* after running an experiment.