# Discrete Random Variables definition explain

Tags: probability, random-variables

Definition: A random variable (r.v.) is a numeric quantity that (i) takes different values with (ii) specified probabilities. [Notation: X, Y, Z, … (capital letters)]

(A random variable is a function from a sample space  into the real numbers.)

[image]

I am not sure I understand the meaning of the definition and especially the math equation showed above. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Did you try searching "math stack exchange random variable definition", and look at this post: [What exactly is a random variable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240673/what-exactly-is-a-random-variable) If that doesn't answer your question, please edit your post to explain what part is unclear, so that someone doesn't have to explain it all from scratch.

Comment: I don't understand is the image.
First S is sample base (for example: I throw a dice and get 1) 
Is the meaning for - X -> equal to put S in a function X?
small x mean we get a real number x?

and next it become (X = x) --> I partially get this, Mean the Capital X and small x mean the same thing?

Comment: Examples may help: (1) roll dice - the possible outcomes are discrete numbers. (2) weigh yourself - outcomes are from a continuous distribution around your average weight.

Comment: The notation of probability is somewhat unique. Students are often used to $f$ for functions and $x$ for a variable, but a random variable ***is*** a function. It's also unique that a capital letter is used for the variable, and the same letter in lower case is used for a value that variable attains (a realization).

Comment: If $S$ is the sample space of three consecutive coin flips, and $X$ is the number of heads, then for example $X(HTH)=2$, and the notation in the picture says that $(X=2)=\{HHT,HTH,THH\}$, so that $P(X=2)=P(\{HHT,HTH,THH\})$, which if the coin flips were all fair would equal $3/8$. The main idea is that if you start with some probability space, which has a sample space and a probability measure on the events, then a "random variable" is a function from the sample space to the real numbers which pushes the probability measure forward to the real numbers.